# Writing concurrent code, non-blocking code

Tags: java, concurrency

Wherever other questions on SO and other sites ask "*How do I write concurrent code?*", the answers always involves pretty vague explanations such as "*check for data dependencies*" or "*interdependencies*" inside the code. I'm wondering what these mysterious dependencies actually look like as Java code!?!

- What's a concrete example of a section of code that can be easily parallelized because it one part doesn't have a dependency on another part?
- What's a concrete example of a section of code that *must* be serial because of the existence of these dependencies?
- How do the existence of these dependencies weigh-in with the decision as to use a thread pool or not?

I guess I'm just not seeing the "forest through the trees" here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's a concrete example of a section of code that can be easily
>   parallelized because it one part doesn't have a dependency on another
>   part?

A concurrent application is build on the execution of `tasks`. You can identify a `task` as any *discrete unit of work*. If you can identify parts of your code that stands out as a discrete unit of work and has explicit *task boundaries*, you can create `Runnable`s for each task and run it in a separate `Thread` achieving parallelism. Actually a `Runnable` represents the `Task` abstraction.
An example would be a process that needs to load multiple files for processing. The loading of files is a discrete unit of work and can be done in the background by threads without blocking the code flow

> What's a concrete example of a section of code that must be serial
>   because of the existence of these dependencies?

If `Task 2` depends on the calculation/processing of `Task 1` then `Task 2` must *wait* for `Task 1` to complete, thereby serializing the sequence.
An example is to load a file in the background and **then** search for a key in the file

> How do the existence of these dependencies weigh-in with the decision
>   as to use a thread pool or not?

They don't. Creating a `Thread` is an expensive operation and `Thread Pools` are a construct design in reusing threads so as to avoid the overhead of creating new ones. In the `Thread Pool` you just pass `Tasks` as `Runnable`s and the `Thread Pool` is responsible to assign the `Task` to a thread or create a new thread if needed. You could also define policies via thread pools etc. But they are a tool for concurrent programs. You are expected to have already identified the tasks to submit to the thread pool for execution.

Comment: Thanks @user! Of all the great answers to this question, you seem to be "getting" what I was *really* asking here, which was more the reasoning of when to parallelize and use multiple threads. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some simple examples:

1.No dependencies, easy to parallelize:

```
 int[] array = new int[size];
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     array[i] = array[i] * array[i];
 }
```

Each item is computed independently.

2.Dependencies on the previous iteration:

```
 int[] array = new int[size];
 for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
     array[i] = array[i - 1] * 2 + array[i];
 }
```

You can't compute `array[3]` until you have `array[2]` (maybe in some cases you can deduce a formula that allows for restructuring, but you get the idea).

The use of thread pools is not really tied to the presence or absence of dependencies. These notions are orthogonal. Thread pools are simply an efficient way of recycling threads, which are generally expensive resources in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to write a bank account object and you want to maintain an invariant -- money is never magically created or destroyed as a result of operations on the bank account.

You might write

```
int balance;

void deposit(int amount) {
  if (amount < 0) { throw ... }
  long after = balance + amount;
  if (after > Integer.MAX_VALUE) { throw ... }
  // DANGER 1
  balance = (int) after;
}

void withdraw(int amount) {
  if (amount < 0 || amount > balance) { throw ... }
  // DANGER 2
  balance -= amount;
}
```

Consider what happens when one thread pauses at either of the DANGER comments and concurrently another deposit or withdrawal happens.

Deposits could be lost if one deposit starts and pauses at DANGER 1 and then another deposit happens, and then the first deposit finishes, clobbering the value.

A withdrawal could push the balance negative if one withdrawal starts, pauses at DANGER 2 and then a deposit happens and then the withdrawal finishes.

Money could be created if a deposit starts, pauses at DANGER 1, then a withdrawal happens, and then the deposit finishes.

---

The standard way to solve this is to say that the code in deposit that computes the `after` value and assigns `balance = (int) after` is a critical section and must happen without any intervening changes to any of its dependencies: `balance`.

Similarly, the safety checks in `withdrawal` and the `-=` operation form a critical section -- the `-=` operation should not happen if the check is not still true.

For bonus fun, consider what might happen because `a -= b` is really several statements under the hood:

```
int x = b;
int y = a;
a = y - x;
```

These all have to happen together for it to be meaningful, so for `a -= b` to have the standard meaning depends on its dependencies `a` and `b` not changing in the middle of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial example where there are no dependencies is any loop going through a collection, doing the same work on every item (a *map* operation, in FP-speak). A typical example where dependencies do exist is business logic with a lot of db fetches, decisions based on them, then further fetches, all in nested ifs -- much data processing, but each step depending on the results of te previous step.